# A more efficient mul-interval

Tags: scheme, sicp, interval

From [2.11](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html)

> Exercise 2.11.  In passing, Ben also
>   cryptically comments: ``By testing the
>   signs of the endpoints of the
>   intervals, it is possible to break
>   mul-interval into nine cases, only one
>   of which requires more than two
>   multiplications.'' Rewrite this
>   procedure using Ben's suggestion.

I wrote the following:

```
(define (negative? . n) (or (= 0 (length n))
                            (and (> 0 (car n)) (apply negative? (cdr n)))))

(define (positive? . n) (or (= 0 (length n))
                            (and (>= (car n) 0) (apply positive? (cdr n)))))

(define (straddles-zero? x) (and (>= 0 (lower-bound x))
                                 (>= (upper-bound x) 0)))

(define (fast-mul-interval x y)
  (let* ((u-x (upper-bound x))
        (u-y (upper-bound y))
        (l-x (lower-bound x))
        (l-y (lower-bound y)))
    (cond 
      ; same sign - max is neg, or min is pos
      ((positive? l-y l-x) (make-interval (* l-x l-y) (* u-x u-y)))
      ((negative? u-y u-x) (make-interval (* u-x u-y) (* l-x l-y)))
      ; x and y have opposite signs
      ((and (positive? l-x) 
            (negative? u-y)) (make-interval (* u-x l-y) (* l-x u-y)))
      ((and (positive? l-y)
            (negative? u-x)) (make-interval (* l-x u-y) (* u-x l-y)))

      ; x straddles zero
      ((straddles-zero? x)
       (if (straddles-zero? y)
           (make-interval (min (* l-x u-y) (* l-y u-x)) 
                          (max (* l-x l-y) (* u-x u-y)))
           (if (negative? u-y)
               (make-interval (* u-x l-y) (* l-x l-y))
               (make-interval (* l-x u-y) (* u-x u-y)))))
      ((straddles-zero? y)
       (if (negative? u-x)
           (make-interval (* u-y l-x) (* l-y l-x))
           (make-interval (* l-y u-x) (* u-y u-x)))))))
```

What do you think?

---

The new version is here:

```
(define (fast-mul-interval x y)
  (let ((l-x (lower-bound x))
        (u-x (upper-bound x))
        (l-y (lower-bound y))
        (u-y (upper-bound y)))
    (cond ((> l-x 0) 
           ;x > 0
           (cond ((> l-y 0)
                  ;y > 0
                  (make-interval (* l-x l-y) (* u-x u-y))
                  )
                 ((< u-y 0)
                  ;y < 0
                  (make-interval (* u-x l-y) (* l-x u-y))
                  )
                 (else
                  ;y contains 0
                  (make-interval (* u-x l-y) (* u-y u-x))
                  ))
           )
          ((> l-y 0)
           ;y > 0
           (if (< u-x 0)
               ; x < 0
               (make-interval (* u-y l-x) (* l-y u-x))
               ; x contains 0
               (make-interval (* l-x u-y) (* u-x l-y))
               )
           )
          ((< u-x 0)
           ;x < 0
           (if (< u-y 0)
               ; y < 0
               (make-interval (* u-x u-y) (* l-x l-y))
               ; y contains 0
               (make-interval (* u-y u-x) (* l-y u-x))
               )
           )
          ((< u-y 0)
           ;y < 0 and x contains 0
           (make-interval (* u-y u-x) (* l-x u-y))
           )
          (else 
           ;x and y both contain 0
           (let ((p1 (* l-x l-y))
                 (p2 (* l-x u-y))
                 (p3 (* u-x u-y))
                 (p4 (* u-x l-y)))
             (make-interval (min p1 p2 p3 p4) (max p1 p2 p3 p4)))
           ))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct.

You may use `let` instead of `let*` since the value of one binding does not depend on the value of another binding.

Since efficiency is important, you can cut back on the number of comparisons as well.  For example, if `u-x` is negative, then `l-x` is also negative and need not be tested.  For this reason, the functions `negative?`, `positive?` and `straddles-zero?` are not necessary.  Instead, you can simply use nested `if`s:

```
(if (< u-x 0)
    ; x is in R < 0
    (if (< u-y 0)
        ; y is in R < 0
        ...
        (if (< l-y 0)
            ; y contains 0
            ...
            ; y is in R >= 0
            ... ))
    (if (< l-x 0)
        ; x contains 0
        ...
        ; x is in R >= 0
        ... ))
```

Comment: You can simplify that further by using `cond`, if I'm not mistaken.